# Azure Static WebApps Deployment Failure Reason: Failure during content distribution

Tags: azure

I have setup a new Static WebApps on Azure and connect it to my github repo. The project is in Next.js. When I am checking the Actions tab, I can see that the build succeeds but the deployment fails with the error:

```
Uploading build artifacts.
Finished Upload. Polling on deployment.
Status: InProgress. Time: 2.1680286(s)
Status: InProgress. Time: 17.5285027(s)
Status: Failed. Time: 32.7463924(s)
Deployment Failed :(
Deployment Failure Reason: Failure during content distribution
Exiting
```

Any ideas on what I might be going on and how to fix it?